# Converting binary word microinstruction to mnemonic

Tags: assembly

The binary words I'm referring to are from this image:

[image]

I have already found what I believe to be correct answers. I just want to double check and be sure.

Line1:

```
R[33] <- SEXT13(R[37]);
```

Line2:

```
R[33] <- ADD(R[rs1], R[33]);
GOTO 1793;
```

Line3:

```
R[33] <- ADD(R[rs1], R[rs2]);
IF R[IR[13]] THEN GOTO 1810;
```

I appreciate any help you can give me

Comment: Welcome to SO! Remember to always give a full description of your problem to help answering your question and for future searches . For example specify the architecture (ARC) and the fact you are talking about *microinstructions* for the microcoded control logic. Also posting references if available (like [this](http://8051-microcontrollers.blogspot.it/2015/01/data-path-and-control-micro.html#.VZ2LVPmqqko)) helps to prevent misunderstanding as not everyone takes your courses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes you are right**

At least if `R[IR[13]]` means the *bit 13* of `%ir` and **not the register with number IR[13]** which could only possibly be `r0` or `r1` as *IR[13]* is a bit.

---

A more detailed analysis:

*Line 1*

```
            A     AMUX    B     BMUX      C   CMUX   WR      RD       ALU     

Binary    100101   0    000000   0    100001   0     0       0        1100
Meaning       37  MIR        0  MIR       33  MIR   No Wr.  No Rd.  SEXT13(A)

                 COND            JUMP ADDR

Binary            000            00000000000
Meaning     Use Next Address             0
```

**Encodes:** `r33 = SEXT13(r37)`, *move to next microcode location*.

*Line 2*

```
            A     AMUX    B     BMUX      C   CMUX   WR      RD       ALU     

Binary    000000   0    100001   0    100001   0     0       0        1100
Meaning        0  rs1       33  MIR       33  MIR   No Wr.  No Rd.  ADD(A,B)

                 COND            JUMP ADDR

Binary            110            11100000001
Meaning     Use Jump Address            1793
```

**Encodes:** `r33 = ADD rs1, r33`, *move to microcode location 1793*.

*Line 3*

```
            A     AMUX    B     BMUX      C   CMUX   WR      RD       ALU     

Binary    000000   0    000000   0    100001   0     0       0        1100
Meaning        0  rs1        0  rs2       33  MIR   No Wr.  No Rd.  ADD(A,B)

                 COND                             JUMP ADDR

Binary            101                           11100010010
Meaning     Use Jump Address if IR[13] = 1             1810
```

**Encodes:** `r33 = ADD rs1, rs2`, *move to microcode location 1810 if %ir[13] is set*.

Where `rs1` and `rs2` are the registers specified in the instruction in `%ir`.